# How to add page history and owner to a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a wiki sharepoint site and I would like to add a field with the information what version is this (version of the page) and who is the owner.

Of course this is visible in Version History when I`m editing the page but is there a way to put this info directly on a page itself ?

I`m interested in "No." field because I already have "modified by". I`m also looking for the owner field but I can`t find it anywhere.

It would be great if someone can guide on how to do it. I`m using online O365 version.

Answer (score 0):

"Created By" is usually associated with the "owner" or "Author" of a piece of content. However depending on how you manage your content it might make sense to manage this in a different way as owners can change if people change departments or leave the company. You may want to make a column called "Content Owner" or something like that so your users can control it.

just create a view in your wiki page library that shows the pages with the  information sorted how you like it and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Is there a way to add such field into the Enterprise Wiki Page ? On a document library I can add a column with the owner and Version.
What I would like to achieve is a small field with version number and owner name but directly on the sharepoint site not in the document library where I can see all of the files etc.

Comment: When I go to page properties I saw this at the bottom.
Version: 17.0
Created at 12/15/2017 2:35 PM  by No presence information Lukasz 
Last modified at 12/29/2017 4:08 PM  by No presence information Lukasz
I would like to have it on my main page + owner field

Comment: I've got a Enterprise Wiki I use as well. I wasn't able to make changes to the wiki page template but I just added a link on the left that shows users the pages from A > Z. If you go to Site Contents you will find an App called "Pages" this is the main library that stores all your wiki pages, going to that app will show you the pages in a list like format. You can then edit columns / manage views as you normally would. If you are on a wiki page see the page ribbon > pages to get to the same place. I would list the page name, version number, and modified info in a view.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to edit the wiki page to show the page information right on the page. You might need to make a copy of a wiki page in SharePoint designer and see what you can modify although I haven't tried that yet. you may want to make a test site to see what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to show fields on Enterprise Wiki page, you should customize the page layout. Using the SharePoint WebControls to show the fields.

1. Navigate to Site Settings page > Master pages and page layouts > create a new page layout > Select “Enterprise Wiki Page” Content Type Name.
2. Edit this page layout using SharePoint Designer.
3. Use FieldValue control to show the value of the field.

Information about WebControls namespace:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols(v=office.14).aspx

A blog about how to display field name and value on the page:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/showing-names-site-columns-page-layout/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is this possible in Sharepoint online because I`m not using onpremis one ?

Comment: I found the fields that are responsible for those values. There are some hide features for those but how to add them to be visible ?

Comment: This is the script that I found

Comment: <script type=text/javascript>
//hide created
$("[id='onetidinfoblock1']").hide();
//hide last modified
$("[id='onetidinfoblock2']").hide();
//hide version
$("[id='onetidinfoblockV']").hide();
</script>